# UICollectionView with selfsizing cells not calculating contentSize properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have UICollection view working with self sizing cells as shown on WWDC 2014.

I want to put it inside a UITableViewCell and display a cloud of tags (good reference of what I want to achieve is in Foursquare application: [image: http://i59.tinypic.com/sxd9qf.png])

My problem is that with self sizing cells, content size is returned not properly.
I prepared some quick demo to show the problem:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        [self.elements addObject:[self randomString]];
    }

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout* layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 30);

    self.collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.contentSize.height);
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.elements count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell* cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.customLabel.text = [self.elements objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    return cell;
}
```

When I do it old way and remove estimatedItemSize and use itemSize instead or delegate method to calculate a size - it works properly, so I think it is using estimatedItem size to get content size.

Is there any way to make it work with self sizing cells and autoresize UICollectionView to it's content ?

Comment: err... I know it's not helping, but I'd recommend not using self-sizing cell in collection views for now. Seems like Apple did a not-so-great job implementing these https://devforums.apple.com/search.jspa?resultTypes=MESSAGE&peopleEnabled=true&q=self-sizing.

Comment: So what will be the way to implement it like I want it ? :) Even with manual calucations I have a problem with predicting how much space I need for UICollectionView to display it's content - I need prediction for UITableViewCell height :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up calculating the size on my own:

```
- (CGSize) sizeForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath isMoreButton:(BOOL) isMoreButton
{
    TagCell* cell = (TagCell*) [[LayoutHelper sharedLayoutHelper] collectionCellFromNib:@"TagCell"];
    cell.tagLabel.text = [self.contactHashTags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
    CGSizeMake(size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
}

- (CGSize) sizeForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath isMoreButton:(BOOL) isMoreButton
{
    CGSize size = [self.dataSource sizeForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath isMoreButton:isMoreButton];

    //limit cell to view width
    size.width = MIN(size.width, self.frame.size.width);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, even in iOS 10 I have the same problem with self-sizing cells. On the next runloop the size is correct. Manual sizing is the only solution.

Comment: This is really annoying. iOS 11 the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround... add an inset on the fly.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let isLastItem = indexPath.item == (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1)
    guard isLastItem else {
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let inset = (cell.frame.maxX - collectionView.contentSize.width) + 10 // 10 is the right padding I want for my horizontal scroll
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: inset)
    }
}
```